# R - Iterating over multiple objects using purrr in combination with pipes

Tags: r, functional-programming, iteration, pipeline, purrr

I'm currently practicing the use of the purrr::map functions.
The most common situation in my case is that I have a list of dataframes/tibbles over which I want to iterate in order to restructure the data and create e.g. different plots.

This works fine as long as I only have one input (my list), but I'm struggeling when providing multiple inputs at different parts of the process.

E.g. let's say I have a simple list with two data.frames with two variables x, and y.
I want to multiply each column by 10 and then plot the results in ggplot, but each graph should have its' own title.

```
my_list <- list("df_1" <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10, b = 1:10),
                "df_2" <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10, b = 10:1))

title <- c("Up", "Down")
```

Using a for loop I would do the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(my_list)){
  print(my_list[[i]]%>% mutate(across(everything(), ~.x * 10)) %>%
                    ggplot(aes(a, b))+
                    geom_line()+
                    ggtitle(title[i]))
}
```

But using the map2 function, the following does not work.

```
my_list %>% map2( y = title, ~.x %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~.x * 10)) %>%
                                ggplot(aes(a, b))+
                                geom_line()+
                                ggtitle(.y)) 

Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default
```

Why is the function argument missing? Isn't the whole pipe operation in ~formula notation supposed to be my function? Using only map instead of map2 and leaving out the ggtitle() step, it works, but doesn't allow me to specify the pipes anywhere.
What is the correct way to approach this, and can this then be easily translated to even more arguments using pmap?

Comment: `y` is not argument `.y` is

Comment: So basically all I was missing was a single "." Using ".y = title", works indeed. Thank you!

I was confused by the text on the help page of the purrr package:

x <- list(1, 1, 1)
y <- list(10, 20, 30)

map2(x, y, ~ .x + .y)

I now understand that this is actually short for map2(.x = x, .y = y, ~ .x + .y)